# Can anyone explain, how this peice of code works?

Tags: python, function, lambda

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n

mydoubler = myfunc(2)

print(mydoubler(11))
```

The value of n = 2, after that I'm confused what is the value of a, and how the lambda function is executed.

Comment: Your function returns a function :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `myfunc` is a nested function, `lambda`s are functions.

An equal implementation would be:

```
def outer(n):
    def inner(a):
        return a * n
    return inner
```

Which returns a function like your original `myfunc` as well. Since the return of the call of `myfunc` is also a function, you may well call the inner function as well.

Answer (score 0):

When the outer function is called, the inner lambda creates a function. The outer lambda then returns the called function.It  happens that describe above..i.e: when we call mydoubler(11),given the value a=11 and call n=2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).